# Is it Possible to recreate Java BufferedReader object, after close()

Tags: java

I created an BufferedReader object to read a file. After completing the file operation successfully I am closing the object something like this:

```
BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("FileName"));
     //Some file operation
buffer.close();
```

Now I need create another BufferedReader object in the same program and So I wanted to create one anther BufferedReader object with the same name *(I need to create object with the **same name** because I want to run the code recursively under some conditions )*.

When I tried, I am getting a message that the object is already present with the same name, **even when I close() the object.**

Can somebody please guide me how to implement this? ***Is there a way to delete the object reference and not just closing it?***
Question can be silly but I haven't work one Java part till now and I can say I am new to it.

Thanks is Advance!

**Error ScreenShot:**

[image]

What I am doing is:

```
  BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("$PropFilePath/WebAndService-Test.details"));
        //Code to read the file and assigning values to some variables
  buffer.close();

  BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("$PropFilePath/ProjectDependencies-Test.List"));
        //Code to use those variables and perform operation on new read file.
  buffer.close();
```

And getting error message, shown in screenshot.

Comment: Closing is not the same as deleting. You can delete the object reference by reassigning `buffer` to a new `BufferedReader`.

Comment: I don't quite understand your problem, can you post the full example, including the creation of the second BufferedReader, and whether your error is a compilation error or at runtime?

Comment: To be simple, I am not able to define object of bufferedReader with the same name again in the same program. 

@Ishnark, your solution is not working, I get the same error message.

Comment: Can you post the source code?

Comment: @VinayVerma you already have `buffer`, so you shouldn't declare `BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(...)` again. You should simply do `buffer = new BufferedReader(...)`

Comment: Thanks @Ishnark, The solution works :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you probably declared `BufferedReader buffer  = ...` twice in the same block. Either use a new variable name `BufferedReader anotheBuffer  = ...` or reuse without declaring `buffer  = ...`. I would suggest a new variable. You should also consider using [`try-with-resources`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Comment: Oops didn't notice your answer before posting mine which is basically the same.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that you are using the wrong syntax when you want to reassign a variable to a new object.

You are doing

```
    BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("FileName"));
```

which is the syntax to use when you are defining a new variable, but to assign a new object to an already existing variable, the correct syntax is

```
    buffer = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("FileName"));
```

as you don't need to tell the compiler again what the type of the variable is.